# How to insert data in one table and ensure that foreign_key in this table exists?

Tags: postgresql

I have two models/tables: Post and Comment.

Post `hasMany` Comments through `Comment.post_id` foreign key.

Now I would like to insert a Comment with specified `post_id` and ensure that Post with `id = post_id` actually exists to avoid situation when there is Comment referencing unexistent Post in database.

So generally I want to atomically:

1. Check if Post with id = post_id exist
2. If it exists insert new Comment with post_id (Post with post_id cant be deleted in the time of insertion of comment)

Comment: Can't you use foreign keys to make sure this rule is enforced?

Comment: Hmm I am not familiar with Postgres - u mean that if I will use foreign key constraint then postgres will return error if I will try to add Comment with invalid post_id?

Comment: Correct, but this is a relational database feature not specific to Postgres, see http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/interactive/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-FK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are describing exactly the reason why foreign key constraints were implemented in relational databases and enforced in the ending 1980ies.